# Devexpress XtraTreeList parent node

Tags: devexpress, parent-child, xtratreelist

I have one treeList that has one parent node and a number of childs. When loading if I click on parent(root) node it is not selected and the eventHandler for the node is not called. Just if I select one of its childs and then select the parent node it will call the eventHandler for selecting that node.
I would appreciate any help on fixing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problemy by seting treeList.FocusedNode to null (or Nothing in VB.NET) in the form constructor and then adding handler for FocusedNodeChanged event (it cannot be assigned in the designer code!).

Regards,

Maciej Nowicki